Unique Pass Index for each point using Geometry Nodes


I have using GeometryNodes to add apples on Tree, but I am trying to give each apple a unique id like Pass Index. So my composite can generate a instance segmentation mask and mark each apple area with different values.

Currently, composition can not access the index of apples and final instance segmentation masks looks like this

Thank you in advance for helping me out. I am 2 weeks old in Blender and relying on Blender tutorials
